# Anyone integrate Particle electron to Azure IoT Central yet?

Tags: azure-iot-central

Particle's Azure IoT Hub integration needs the IoT Hub Name, Shared Policy Name, and Shared Policy Key. The connection string in IoT Central gives the Key, but I have not been able to guess what the hub name and policy name are to be able to pipe my Particle cloud data into IoT Central.

Would be nice to have, that'd be the ultimate for quick up and running proof of concepts!

Comment: @ndmeiri - what is the value and purpose to edit my post and add a comma? Does this somehow give you points on stackoverflow? Pretty non-value added, hope you don't get something for that edit...

Answer (score 1):

Azure IoT Central recently released [Device bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/howto-build-iotc-device-bridge) which is an open-source solution that connects Sigfox, Particle, The Things Network, and other clouds to your Azure IoT Central app. You can access the open source solution from [Github](https://aka.ms/iotcentralgithubdevicebridge).